# GCM message does not reach destination in PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to send a GCM notification given a server action of `sendGroupMessage`. At present, the GCM message does not send though I have implemented the its' functionality to react as `echo $testGCM;`

```
case "sendGroupMessage":
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password, $gcmregid)) 
        {   
            if (isset($_REQUEST['toGroupId']))
            {   // instead of toUserName it's to a groupId
                $toGroupName = $_REQUEST['toGroupName'];
                $toGroupId   = $_REQUEST['toGroupId'];  
                $message     = $_REQUEST['messageText'];
                $campaign    = $_REQUEST['campaign_id'];
                $location    = $_REQUEST['location_id'];

                // Query to get the users id's who are in the group but not the user sending the message        
                $sqlGroupMembers = "SELECT DISTINCT usersId from users_groups 
                     WHERE usersId != '".$userId."' AND groupId = '".$toGroupId."'";


                // Loop to create a copy of message for all users taht are part of that group
                if($getGroupMembersId = $db->query($sqlGroupMembers)) 
                {
                    while($rowGroupMembers = $db -> fetchObject($getGroupMembersId))
                    {
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `group_messages` (`myId`,`fromUser`, `fromUId`,`toGroupName`,`toGroupId`, `sentdt`, `read`, `readdt`, `messageText`,`shared_campaign_id`,`shared_campaign_location_id`) 
                              VALUES ('".$rowGroupMembers->usersId."','".$username."', '".$userId."','".$toGroupName."', '".$toGroupId."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '0', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."','".$campaign."','".$location."');";                        

                        error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                        if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                        {
                                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                echo testGCM(); // Testing the actions
                        }               
                        else 
                        {
                                $out = FAILED;
                        }                   

                    }   

                }                   

            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           

        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
```

The testGCM action:

```
function testGCM() {
    $gcmRegID  =  '(users GCM regID)'
    $pushMessage = $_POST["syncNewData"];   
    if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {      
        $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
        $message = array("syncNewData" => $pushMessage);    
        $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
    }       
}
```

sendNotification method:

```
function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
        define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "(Google API Key)"); // My API Key form Google console
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);               
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "does not send"? What happens? Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors, the message just does not send. Is this the proper implementation to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some issue with your testGCM() function. Can you log the `$pushStatus` variable to see what is there or is it null. Also there is no code where you are parsing the JSON array returned after the request. You can check the error logs in logcat to investigate the issue.

Here are some tutorials that would help you find more about the implementation issues:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

https://github.com/mattg888/GCM-PHP-Server-Push-Message

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial/

Hope this helps!!!